# Allow saving password when connect to server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF designer to connect to the server database. When I initiating connection string through wizard, I found this check box 'Allow saving password' and also 'exclude sensitive data from the connection string'. Since no one wants to let others to know their password, I'm wondering how does this option affects the whole application. I already googled it but there are no useful info about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a checkbox and it allows you to store the password in your connection string. Nothing to do with user's credentials; only relates to db access.

Comment: what happen if I don't add to the connection string? how do I connect to the server?

Comment: Credentials aren't required in the connection string if you use integrated security which will use the user account that the application is served from. If you need a primer on connection strings check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think you are confusing the EF connection string with actual user authentication. They are separate.